# Recompiling apk with apktool

Tags: android, xml, apk, apktool

When I try to use `apktool b .apk`, it shows the following error:

```
I: Using Apktool 2.7.0
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Building resources...
brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/brut_util_Jar_82197003944312111479219531023469594915.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 21, --target-sdk-version, 29, --rename-manifest-package, com.aliucord.installer2, --version-code, 107, --version-name, 1.0.7, --no-version-vectors, -F, /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/APKTOOL5369737272708573366.tmp, -e, /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/APKTOOL17725436950078718587.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.local/share/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /storage/emulated/0/Download/DAPK/Aliucord/res, -M, /storage/emulated/0/Download/DAPK/Aliucord/AndroidManifest.xml]
W: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/brut_util_Jar_82197003944312111479219531023469594915.tmp[1]: can't create �c,@f-@8: Operation not permitted
W: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/brut_util_Jar_82197003944312111479219531023469594915.tmp[714]: syntax error: unexpected '('
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you use apktool in termux? If yes use this [apktool for termux](https://github.com/rendiix/termux-apktool)